# HTML5 placing image where i want it on screen

Tags: css, html

I have a little start screen running and i want the image, which is acting as a button, to placed at a certain point, but when i try to it stays in the same place, and i don't know how i can get it to stay in the place i want it. Here is my code, its is HTML with some css:

```
<style>
    #SplashScreen{
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    #StartButton
    {
        cursor:pointer;
        position:absoloute;
        left:100px;
        top:100px;
    }
</style>
<div id="SplashScreen" width="400" height="400">
    <h1>Game Title</h1>
    <img id="StartButton" src="play.png"/>
</div>
```

The image just draws underneath the title and not where i want it. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your `absolute` spelling is wrong

```
#StartButton
{
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    left:100px;
    top:100px;
}
```

And don't use height/width attributes, specify them in your `#SplashScreen` instead [**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9B37v/)

```
<style>
    #SplashScreen{
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;
        height: 400px;
        width: 400px;

    }

    #StartButton
    {
        cursor:pointer;
        position:absolute;
        left:100px;
        top:100px;
    }
</style>
<div id="SplashScreen">
    <h1>Game Title</h1>
    <img id="StartButton" src="http://www.alfresco.com/community/images/windows-icon.png"/>
</div>​
```

Comment: Wow, that's embarrassing. Thanks for taking the time to answer my terrible question. I should really check my code better. I've only been coding a month or two. I've got allot to learn :)

Comment: @corrigan_sam You should select the answers as correct so that others can refer ;)

Comment: Yea i was going to, its just that i have to wait a certain amount of time before i could, don't worry. ill be voting your answer up :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you mispelled `absolute`, and if you want to set width and height to a div you have to do it throught CSS, not in the html tag

```
#SplashScreen{
        position:relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
    }

    #StartButton
    {
        cursor:pointer;
        position: absolute;
        left:200px;
        top:100px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background: black;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I've only been coding for a month or two so excuse my noob questions :)

Comment: It's ok, that's what stackoverflow is for, just make sure you tried to research a bit first.

Also, try using an editor (for example I use coda2 in OSX) that colour the keywords, to avoid those small mistakes, that can make you wonder what happened for hours xD

Comment: Yea i use notepad++, but it was inside a html5 document so it does not highlight them.